# What language is this artists signature written in and what does it say?

Tags: language

This signature is on a print from the 1960s. There are symbols in the art such as a fish (see ring and vest clasp)and a hamsa (possibly) in the outer border.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like japanese katakana: https://severalingvo.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/277250-katakanachart.png
  Do you know the origin of the art?

Comment: I see the similarity to Japanese Katakana but don't see the "dots" underneath the letter as in the art.I don't know the origin. I thought perhaps an Israeli artist because of the hamsa and fishes in art. And I believe the 1960's because of the style of hair & clothing.

Comment: Why assume that it is anything other than a highly-stylized idiosyncratic signature? Artists do weird things sometimes.

Comment: [Here's a rabbit hole for you to fall down](http://www.artistssignatures.com/index.php).

Comment: John: I will consider that it may be an artist's signature but want to rule out that it is a written language first.

Spencer: And yes, I will check out that very deep rabbit hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Hebrew alphabet, רִיקִי "Riki" (or "Ricky"). Note the position of the signature on the canvas – in the bottom left corner, in Hebrew it's "the end of the text" position since they write right to left. The European painters usually sign in the bottom right corner, in the European "end of the text" position, because Europeans write left to right. When the painting is finished, as the last stroke the painters put their signatures, thus finishing the work.
 Also, a dot beneath a letter is typical for Hebrew, such a dot is called [Hiriq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiriq) and denotes the [i] sound, like in 'sit', 'pin', or 'give.' And yes, that is very likely *hamsas* in the outer border.
 Unfortunately, I have no idea who Riki/Ricky is or who signed paintings like that.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: 'Riqi' could also yield results since the third letter could also be transcribed 'q'.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer seems to be correct about it being Hebrew, though in my (extensive) experience the choice of location for a signature is fairly random even for an individual artist.

That work was done by Riki Ben Ari, an Israeli fashion illustrator active in the 60s through the 80s (or beyond?). She died in 2007. An obit. stated she was "The high priestess of fashion[...]" in Israel.

Not a lot of imagery available, but below is an example, albeit signed using the "latin alphabet" ([source](https://www.periscopedesigngallery.com/fashio-in-a-line))

[image]

Comment: I believe you're probably right about Ben-Ari.  Although, on [this page](https://www.periscopedesigngallery.com/fashio-in-a-line) we can see a pretty consistent signature that is quite different from the one in the original post.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, and my illustration certainly appears to be from Riki Ben Ari. Your post enabled me to find archives on The National Library of Israel site. Thank you https://www.nli.org.il/he/archives/NNL_ARCHIVE_AL997009648085305171/NLI?utm_source=he.wikipedia.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=%22%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99+%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%22&utm_content=nliarchive

Answer (score 0):

An image search of both the signature and poster didn't provide answers - but turned up a lot of Aubrey Beardsley's work - and this artist is obviously influenced by Beardsley. Of course many 60's artists were also. Might be worth contacting a gallery who specializes in '60s posters and other art.  It is a fascinating piece. I'd love to know more.